# New React context API and flow error, when trying to render Consumer

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

When I try to render Consumer, flow show next error:

> [flow] Cannot create `SidebarContextConsumer` element because property `changeOpenState` is missing in undefined [1] in the first argument of property `children`. (References: [1])

Here my code:

```js
// @flow
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

import type { Context, ProviderProps } from './Sidebar.types';

const SidebarContext = createContext();

export const SidebarContextConsumer = SidebarContext.Consumer;

/* eslint-disable react/no-unused-state */
export class SidebarContextProvider extends React.Component<ProviderProps, Context> {

  state = {
    dynamic: false,
    open: false,
    transition: false,
    changeDynamicMode: (dynamic: boolean) => {
      this.setState({
        dynamic,
        open: false,
        transition: false,
      });
    },
    changeOpenState: (open: boolean, transition: boolean = true) => {
      this.setState({ open, transition });
    },
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <SidebarContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {children}
      </SidebarContext.Provider>
    );
  }

}
/* eslint-enable */
```

Flow declaration:

```
export type Context = {
  changeDynamicMode: (dynamic: boolean) => void,
  changeOpenState: (open: boolean, transition?: boolean) => void,
  dynamic: boolean,
  open: boolean,
  transition: boolean,
};
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems to be a [known limitation](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2916#issuecomment-263523543) of flowtype.

I resolved the error in my case with:

```js
const SidebarContext: Object = createContext();
```

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR This can be solved by adding a default to `createContext`

I think the problem is that Flow there is a logical flaw in how Flow interacts with `React.createContext()`. First, we can specify the context value by using `React.Context<myObject>`. Unfortunately if we don't specify a default parameter Flow *correctly* realizes that the `myObject` can be `undefined`.

A simple test case to that you can play around with at [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnBAEYBWcAvHAG8APigBccVDCjAAdgHMANHA7iZAVxAcsUOEIC+dXBBmS4+AB4xx2PDAB0AYWMwslgDwB+TlwB8fTFT2uJTILk4yLpYAFACU9IbGprjgEf6xfH5RdHBwbhb2AArEAG7AACbacMXIADZqWLwCAmJwAETIrUoqcABMcHp6Ptk5ufmOiRraQyMjAlECyHoxGWaJEDVYdjUQclHIdjAQAKpgrFAOaFixMQYzbgD0Y+Gok1DTuY8wlnZFEKUVbziQA):

import * as React from 'react';

```js
type obj = {| a: string, b: number |}
const ctxt: React.Context<?obj> = React.createContext();

const cmpnt = () => (
  <ctxt.Provider value={{ a: "a", b: 2 }}>
    <ctxt.Consumer>
      {({a}) => console.log(a.toUpperCase())}
    </ctxt.Consumer>
  </ctxt.Provider>);
```

As you can see the error in Flow 0.78:

```js
{({a}) => console.log(a.toUpperCase())}
 ^ Cannot create `ctxt.Consumer` element because property `a` is missing in null or undefined [1] in the first argument of property `children`.

References:

4: const ctxt: React.Context<?obj> = React.createContext();
```

If we add a `default` it disappears:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

type obj = {| a: string, b: number |}
const ctxt: React.Context<obj> = React.createContext({ a: "test", b: 2 });

const cmpnt = () => (
  <ctxt.Provider value={{ a: "a", b: 2 }}>
    <ctxt.Consumer>
      {({a}) => console.log(a.toUpperCase())}
    </ctxt.Consumer>
  </ctxt.Provider>);
```

## Suggested fix to the original problem

```js
import * as React from 'react';

type Context = {
  changeDynamicMode: (dynamic: boolean) => void,
  changeOpenState: (open: boolean, transition?: boolean) => void,
  dynamic: boolean,
  open: boolean,
  transition: boolean,
};

const defaultState: Context = {
  dynamic: false,
  open: false,
  transition: false,
  changeDynamicMode: (dynamic: boolean) => console.error('Fix function!', dynamic),
  changeOpenState: (open: boolean, transition: boolean = true) => console.error('Fix function!', open, transition),
}

const ctxt = React.createContext(defaultState);

class SidebarContextProvider extends React.Component<mixed & { children: React.Node }, Context> {

  state = {
    dynamic: false,
    open: false,
    transition: false,
    changeDynamicMode: (dynamic: boolean) => {
      this.setState({
        dynamic,
        open: false,
        transition: false,
      });
    },
    changeOpenState: (open: boolean, transition: boolean = true) => {
      this.setState({ open, transition });
    },
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <ctxt.Provider value={this.state}>
        {children}
      </ctxt.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me

```
export const SidebarContextConsumer = ((SidebarContext.Consumer: any):
  React$ComponentType<{
    children: (value: Context) => ?React$Node
  }>
);
```

I've casted through any and restored original Consumer typedef but with maybe type of value removed

```
React$ComponentType<{ children: (value: ?Context) => ?React$Node}>
```

Answer (score 0):

With flow, this is how I would usually type context (without initial value):

`const SidebarContext = createContext<Context | typeof undefined>();`

where `Context` is your custom defined `type`.

What also might be useful is using [exact type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types) for your `Context` so flow will throw an error if somebody would try to use attribute/key which is not defined in `Context type`.